# Google Sheet SUBSTITUTE and CONVERT TO NUMBER

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a SS where I need to convert a string to a real formula.

I have a variable that can be changed and I want to substitute it to all my strings, which could be writing (and simple) calculs.

For example, if #variable = 3, I want to convert "20+#variable" to "23".
At the same time, I want to keep the text if relevant, for example, "#variable turns" should convert into "3 turns" (this is the step I reached).

I used `=VALUE(Col4)` to get the error on Col5 :

[image]

You can find the example in the Substitute sheet here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qBGkWETY2fcUks2gsPgeRSaG_RuFkOmik0_WKNs1nUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&D2);2); D2)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&REGEXREPLACE(D6, "(?i)[a-z ]", )), 2)&
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D6, "(?i)[a-z ]+")), D6)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it's working with the numeric values ! Thanks a lot !

I get when there is text, that won't apply and we get the value from IFERROR right ?
Would there be a way to trigger it for text + numbers ?

I added an example in the test sheet

Comment: @BattlePoap answer updated